# Print Vec using a placeholder

Tags: vector, rust

I am trying to print a `Vec` with variables of other datatypes:

```
let a = 4;
let b = vec![1,2,3,4];
let c = 3;

// printing input
println!("a: {0}, b: {1}, c: {2}", a, b, c);
```

but I get this error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::vec::Vec<{integer}>: std::fmt::Display` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:23:43
   |
23 |     println!("a: {0}, b: {1}, c: {2}", a, b, c);
   |                                           ^ trait `std::vec::Vec<{integer}>: std::fmt::Display` not satisfied
   |
   = note: `std::vec::Vec<{integer}>` cannot be formatted with the default formatter; try using `:?` instead if you are using a format string
   = note: required by `std::fmt::Display::fmt`
```

How do I print the `Vec` at a particular position in the output string?

Comment: try using `:?` instead?

Comment: `println!("a: {0}, b: {1:?}, c: {2}", a, b, c)`. Using the numbers in *this* case is silly though, you should just use `println!("a: {}, b: {:?}, c: {}", a, b, c)`. Refer to the [`fmt` module documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/) for the complete list of what you can use to format and the appropriate syntax.

Comment: how do I mention the position and :? together?

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful :)